# Storing of threadlocal variable

Tags: java

I have a very simple question. Given that Threadlocal variables are declared with static modifier, it is expected that it will be stored in heap. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: `ThreadLocal` variables are not necessarily static.

Comment: Of course to find the current thread to find the thread-local, the implementation is like to go through the current stack (although, to be honest, I'm not entirely sure of the implementation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[All Java objects (reference types) are stored on the heap.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.3) It has nothing to do with `static`.

> #### 2.5.3 Heap
>
> The Java Virtual Machine has a *heap* that is shared among all Java Virtual Machine threads. The heap is the run-time data area from which memory for all class instances and arrays is allocated.